# how to call 2 javascript on client click event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to call 2 javascript one time on client click event.  I am only able to call them one of the javascript.  Once the user clicks the button, i want to call 2 javascript because each javascript is checking 2 diferent gridviews.  How can i call both of them one time on client click event.  Here is my button

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="return validate_1();" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click"> 
     <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Submit
     </asp:LinkButton>
```

here is the 1st one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate_1() {
            var flag = true;
            var dropdowns = new Array(); //Create array to hold all the dropdown lists.
            var gridview = document.getElementById('<%=Main_GV.ClientID%>'); //GridView1 is the id of ur gridview.
            dropdowns = gridview.getElementsByTagName('Select'); //Get all dropdown lists contained in GridView1.
            for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                if (dropdowns.item(i).value == 'Select') //If dropdown has no selected value
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break; //break the loop as there is no need to check further.
                }
            }
            if (!flag) {
                alert('Warning.....  Thanks');
                document.getElementById('<%=btn_Submit.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            return flag;         

        }
    </script>
```

here is the 2nd one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function validate_2() {

            var f = document.getElementById('<%=GV_Test.ClientID%>');
            for (var i = 0; i < f.getElementsByTagName("input").length ; i++) {
                if (f.getElementsByTagName("input").item(i).type == "text") {

                    if (f.getElementsByTagName("input").item(i).value == 0) {
                        alert("warning....");
                        f.getElementsByTagName("input").item(i).focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    </script>
```

i want to call both validate_1() and validate_2().  Thanks

Comment: Why dont you call fuction call inside a fuction.That means `function  validate_1() { //your stuff ; validate_2()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about :

```
return OnClientClick="return validate_1() && validate_2();"
```

If validate_1 doesn't pass then validate_2 will not get called.  So if both functions return truthy, then your postback will take place.